# Using partition method in splitting a sequence

Tags: scala, function, object

I have a sequence say a  which is like

```
val a:Seq[Any]=Seq("Hai",1,2,"Hello")
```

Now I want to split this sequence to 2 different sequence `seqString` is with Datatype `String` and `seqInt` is with datatype `Int` .

```
scala> val partitioned =a.partition(p => p.isInstanceOf[String])
```

this splits my sequence to 2 sequence which is `Seq("Hai", "Hello")` and `Seq(1,2)`. Now Suppose I want to Operate on the sequence that I have derived  if I try

```
scala>partitioned._2.map(x => x+1)
```

I am unable to perform this operation as the resultant from partition method returns `Seq[Any]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with multiple traversals, try out a `collect` with a `case` statement:

```
scala> val a:Seq[Any]=Seq("Hai",1,2,"Hello")
a: Seq[Any] = List(Hai, 1, 2, Hello)

scala> val partitioned = (a.collect{case x: Int => x}, a.collect{case x: String => x})
partitioned: (Seq[Int], Seq[String]) = (List(1, 2),List(Hai, Hello))

scala> partitioned._1.map(_ * 2)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured out another way. This could be done using foldLeft

```
   a.foldLeft((Seq[String](),Seq[Int]()))((accum,b) =>
    b match{
    case i:Int => (accum._1,accum._2 :+i)
    case s:String => (accum._1 :+s,accum._2)
    case _ => accum
    })
```